# Using stub in rspec to test output of a rand

Tags: ruby, rspec, stub

I have a class Weather, that should return random results and I'd like to test it using [method stub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub). I read the article written by Martin Flower on this [page](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) and I feel it would be the easiest solution. But it's difficult to find any examples of syntax.

Could you give me an example of a test? This is part of my homework.

```
class Weather

  def conditions
   return :good if chance > 0.3
   :stormy
  end

  def chance
   rand
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example, you want to test the behavior of `chance` not the implementation.

```
describe Weather do
  it 'returns good' do
    weather = Weather.new
    allow(weather).to receive(:chance).and_return(0.8)
    expect(weather.conditions).to eq :good
  end
end
```